# Define $f(k \pi)$ so that $f$ is continuous at $k \pi$

Tags: real-analysis

> Define $f(k \pi)$ so that $f$ is continuous at $k \pi$ , 
>   given that: $$f(x) = \frac{\sin nx}{n\sin x}$$ with $$ x \neq k \pi, k \in \mathbb Z, n \in \mathbb Z^+$$

I am new to real analysis, I do not really understand how $f$ can be continuous at $k \pi$ ,

When $n=1$, $f(x)=\frac{\sin x}{\sin x}$, so $f$ is not defined at $k \pi$

When $n=2$, similar ..

What would be the best approach here?

Comment: you need to calculate the limit of $f$ from two sides, and then define a function at $k\pi$, so it will be equal to wishfully equal limits

Comment: Functions may, if they satisfy some conditions,  be redefined so that they are continuous. They are asking you to decide if this applies for your function.

Comment: @gary I am trying to find out about those conditions but my resource book is anything but clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since$$\lim_{x\to k\pi}\frac{\sin nx}{n\sin x}=\lim_{x\to k\pi}\frac{n\cos nx}{n\cos x}=\frac{\cos nk\pi}{\cos k\pi}=\frac{(-1)^{nk}}{(-1)^k}=(-1)^{(n-1)k}\text,$$all you have to do is to define $f(k\pi)$ as $(-1)^{(n-1)k}.$

Comment: How do you proceed from $\frac{\sin nx}{n\sin x}$ to $\frac{n\cos nx}{n\cos x}$  ?

Comment: @gegu Using [L'Hôpital's rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%27H%C3%B4pital%27s_rule).

Comment: thx for the input, One more little question:  i am not understanding the reasoning to go from  \frac{\cos nk\pi}{\cos k\pi}  to \frac{(-1)^{nk}}{(-1)^k}

Comment: @gegu That's because $\cos(N\pi)=(-1)^N$, for each integer $N$.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: $$\lim_{x \to k\pi}\frac{\sin nx}{n\sin x}=\lim_{x \to k\pi}\left(\frac{\sin nx}{nx} \times\frac{x}{\sin x}\right)$$

Answer (score 1):

That's the reason why you're supposed to *define* $f(k\pi)$.

f is continuous at $k\pi$, when $\lim_{x\to k\pi}f(x) = f(k\pi)$. Try to calculate that limit for any $k,z$.