# How do you proceed from $\frac{\sin nx}{n\sin x}$ to $\frac{n\cos nx}{n\cos x}$?

Tags: trigonometry

How do you proceed from $\frac{\sin nx}{n\sin x}$ to $\frac{n\cos nx}{n\cos x}$  ?

Long time I did not deal with trig. I cannot find which trig identity involved .

Much appreciated

Comment: I think you are missing an application of de l'Hopital's theorem, rather than a trigonometric identity.

Comment: What do you mean by "proceed"? The two functions are not equal, I think.

Comment: this is an example of where providing context is essential to finding a solution to the problem

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you are referring to [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2358934/406460) to your previous question, yes?

It is not that $\frac{\sin(nx)}{n \sin x} = \frac{n \cos(nx)}{n \cos x}$. Rather,

$$\lim_{x \to k\pi} \frac{\sin(nx)}{n \sin x} = \lim_{x \to k\pi} \frac{n \cos(nx)}{n \cos x}$$.

This is due to an application of L'Hopital's rule. We can use it since both the denominator and the numerator go to 0 as $x$ goes to $k\pi$.

Comment: good detective work :) @gegu this is an example of [L'Hopital](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%27H%C3%B4pital%27s_rule), where as emma described, if the limit takes a certain indefinite form, we can differentiate the numerator and denominator w.r.t. $x$ and preserve equality. here, $$ \frac{d[\sin nx]}{dx} = n \cos nx ,\ \frac{d[n \sin x]}{dx} = n \cos x $$

Comment: Yes Emma it was in relation with a previous question. really grateful for the help.

Comment: No problem! But as @Dando18 mentioned above, in the future if you ask a question that's referring to another question it is very helpful to provide the context in your post.